# Unable retrieve records from SQLite database for smart device application

Tags: c#, sqlite, smart-device

I am using SQLite.NET with C#[ visual studio 2008] and added the 'System.Data.SQLite.dll' as reference. The following code works with Windows Application for fetching data from my database file into a datagrid.

```
    private void SetConnection()
    {
        sql_con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=emp.db;Version=3;");
    }

    public DataTable LoadData()
    {
        SetConnection();
        sql_con.Open();
        sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
        string CommandText = "select * from employeedetails";
        transaction=sql_con.BeginTransaction();
        DA = new SQLiteDataAdapter(CommandText, sql_con);
        DS.Reset();
        DA.Fill(DS);
        DT = DS.Tables[0];
        transaction.Commit();
        sql_con.Close();
        return DT;
    }
```

**Invoking in:**

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EmpTable obj = new EmpTable();     
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = obj.LoadData();
    }
```

The same code not working with C# 'Smart Device Application'. It shows an exception: no such table 'employeedetails'.

For Smart Device Application I have added the System.Data.SQLite.dll from "SQLite/CompactFramework" folder.

Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using same database file in pc and device?

Comment: ya, I using the database 'emp.db' in both Applications.

Comment: try to specify full path to database. seems to me that your device app cant reach it

Comment: What's the purpose of the transaction on a select statement?

Comment: Is this happening when running a deployed version or running against an emulator?

Comment: Seems to be creating a new database as it can't find the existing one. Add 'failifmissing=True' onto your SQLite connection string. It will raise a SQLiteException if the database can't be found instead of creating a blank empty one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank You Guys,

I've resolved the Problem. As 'siyw' said, the problem was the application could not find the "db file".

**For windows application,**

The db file has to be located in debug folder where the .exe file is generated. So that, no need to specify the path of the DB file.

**For Smart Device Application,**

The DB file will be generated in the root folder of the device. If we bind the db file with exe means, it wont find it and it will create a new database in root folder.

To avoid that, while crating CAB file we have to create custom folder [ ex. DBfolder ] and put the db file in the folder.
   Set the path in the connection String as,

```
sql_con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=DBfolder/emp.db;Version=3;");
```

Now, the db is found by the Application.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is what is causing your issue, but we've had issues in the past with mobile devices and sqlite where this solved it:

For an application using the compact framework, you need to include SQLite.Interop.xxx.DLL in your project (in addition to the regular System.Data.SQLite.DLL). Make sure you set the file to *copy if newer* or *copy always*.

Keep in mind that you can't set a reference to the interop dll. You must include it in the project by adding it as a file.

For more information check [this website](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/readme.htm) under the *Distributing The SQLite Engine and ADO.NET Assembly* section.

Answer (score 1):

```
sql_con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=emp.db;Version=3;");
```

I think you need to specify the full path here, and make sure it's correct. If the path is to a non-existent file, it will create a new emp.db database file there instead. This new file will obviously be empty and without any tables, hence it would give a `no such table 'employeedetails'` exception such as you're getting if you query it.

Comment: +1 Good point. We also ran into that one as well. I think this is more likely the issue than what I suggested.